# ASP.Net Core API: How to link User Identity to a Contact

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working on an app that takes advantage of ASP.Net Core's User/Role identity tables in SQL.

Due to the nature of the app I am building right now, public registration is out of the question. What I am looking to build would require an admin of the app to first add the new employee as a contact into the app. After saving their contact info, they would click a button to set that contact up as a user.

What would be your recommended approach to either extend the identity framework or link AspNetUsers with my Contacts table to accomplish this goal. I am sure I will be querying information from both sides of this setup often and this is my primary reason for asking this question.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide additional details.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentityUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdentityUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do they have one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Yes, the contact would have a one-to-one relationship with the user profile.

Comment: Since you're saying you'll be querying both of them then I think extending the IdentityUser would be a good choice

Comment: How might I accomplish this while keeping the contact in its own table? Can I simply do an ICollection in the extended IdentityUser table to the contact? I apologize, I am not sure the best way to link it. Something like the above? Obviously more too it but...

Comment: Then I suggest a simple one-to-one relationship or EF Core owned types ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities))

Comment: In this context, the owned attribute would go on the User Identity table? To me, it doesn't make sense doing it the other way as there could be numerous contacts without a user account.

Comment: You can configure owned types to be on seperate tables. read the [Storing owned types in separate tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#storing-owned-types-in-separate-tables) section

Comment: Oh I think I get where you are going with this. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Actually this may be a deal break in this context: You cannot create a DbSet<T> for an owned type. I do need to be able to access both the Contact and the User from AspNetUsers independently.

Comment: So I guess that leaves you with one-to-one relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Contact` can exist without `User` but a `User` cannot exist without a `Contact`. A simple one-to-one relationship:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    int ContactId { get; set; }
    Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    int? UserId { get; set; }
    User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great..thank you for the help. I will give that I try in the AM.